# How to use JWT to preserve client session to a non-SPA application?

Tags: javascript, jwt, token

I've tried using JWT to my first SPA project (using Angular). In there, I store the JWT returned after login to localstorage. I was able to access it and pass as authorization header to every request.

Now that I have a NodeJS app serving the api and html/css/js how can I properly store it to the client to preserve his session?

Comment: You could get the header using request.getResponseHeader('Authorization') after login, then store in localstorage and   use  beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', take_authoization_header_from_local_storage); 
    }
before sending request  to server

Comment: Yes, that is my first option to store it to localstorage. However, some article do not recommend to store in localstorage instead cookies httponly. That's why I'm looking for other solution